# Differences between react-native-ble-plx vs react-native-ble-manager

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx, react-native-ble-manager

I found the following libraries that support BLE for react native, I wanted to know the opinion of those who have had the opportunity to try them, if you have tried them.

1. Can you tell me the differences between them?
2. What are the pros and cons of each of them?
3. Which of the two do you recommend?

On the side of the update I saw that the latest updates of:

- [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx) dates to Dec 9, 2021
- [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) dates back to Apr 6, 2023

Comment: Your question seems opinion based and not focused :/